# Can't center navbar elements

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that contains elements, and I'm not able to center them in the middle of the navbar. I do not want to use bootstrap. Whatever I do, it still starts from the left side. I originally had the ul as the .topnav but it still wasn't centering the elements.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <ul >
              <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Products</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Computers</a>
                    <a href="#">Tablets</a>
                    <a href="#">Cell Phones</a>
                    <a href="#">Wearable Technologies</a>
                    <a href="#">Accessories</a>
                  </div>
              </li>  
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Brands</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Apple</a>
                    <a href="#">Samsung</a>
                    <a href="#">Lenovo</a>
                    <a href="#">Dell</a>
                    <a href="#">HP</a>
                    <a href="#">Sony</a>
                    <a href="#">Panasonic</a>
                    <a href="#">Motorola</a>
                    <a href="#">HTC</a>
                  </div>
              </li> 
              <li><a href="deals.html">Deals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.topnav{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align:center;
    align-items: center;
}

.topnav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.topnav li {
    float: left;
}

.topnav li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:100px;
}

.topnav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #111;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.topnav .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29r9d18a/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.topnav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}
```

You will no longer need the `auto` x-margin on the `ul` element with `inline-block` positioning and the parents center aligning, but you may want to override Safari's auto padding which will push it to the right slightly on Macs.

Comment: Thanks! This worked and also fixed the shift to the right!

Answer (score 1):

Update the class definition

```
.topnav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29r9d18a/7/)

Answer (score 0):

**Use display: flex AND text-align: center**

```
.topnav{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    display: flex; //HERE
    text-align: center !important; //HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the '.topnav ul' class to the following in your css code :

```
    .topnav ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left: 27%;
    }
```

This will shift your list to a bit right side and thus show it on the center.